# MATLAB suppress MEX compilation output except for "success" statement?

Tags: c, matlab, compilation, compiler-warnings, mex

I am using the Legacy Code Tool to convert C code into a MEX file using the command `legacy_code('generate_for_sim',def)` (description [here](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/integrating-existing-c-functions-into-simulink-models-with-the-legacy-code-tool.html)). However, the C compiler gives a lot of warnings which do not actually prevent the compiled program from running correctly. I want to suppress these warnings. In particular, the output currently looks something like this (I replaced sensitive information with `****`):

```
### Start Compiling *****************************
    mex(*****************************)
Building with 'MinGW64 Compiler (C)'.

*****************************:44:6: note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'idxint *'
*****************************
   ^
In file included from *****************************:42:0:
*****************************:44:6: note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'idxint *'
*****************************
   ^
In file included from *****************************:42:0:
*****************************:44:6: note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'idxint *'
 *****************************
      ^

MEX completed successfully.
    mex(*****************************)
Building with 'MinGW64 Compiler (C)'.
MEX completed successfully.
    mex(*****************************)
Building with 'MinGW64 Compiler (C)'.
MEX completed successfully.
    mex(*****************************)
Building with 'MinGW64 Compiler (C)'.
MEX completed successfully.
    mex(*****************************)
Building with 'MinGW64 Compiler (C)'.
MEX completed successfully.
    mex(*****************************)
Building with 'MinGW64 Compiler (C)'.
MEX completed successfully.
    mex(*****************************)
Building with 'MinGW64 Compiler (C)'.

C:*****************************: In function 'CheckDataTypes':
C:*****************************:809:5: warning: this decimal constant is unsigned only in ISO C90
     *****************************
     ^
C:*****************************:809:5: warning: this decimal constant is unsigned only in ISO C90

MEX completed successfully.
### Finish Compiling sfun_ecos
### Exit
All done
```

I want, however, to output only the start and end (to indicate to the user that the compilation was successful) without showing all the intermediate information and warnings. The result should be:

```
### Start Compiling *****************************
MEX completed successfully.
### Finish Compiling sfun_ecos
### Exit
All done
```

Thank you in advance for helping me to achieve this.

Comment: At least it looks like that in the compiler call the verbosity option is enabled by `mex -v`...